# How to print out size of physical memory in linux

Tags: linux, memory-size

If I use this `grep MemTotal /proc/meminfo` in linux terminal, I get `MemTotal:        2059908 kB`.

Does anybody know how to get numbers only? which will be `2059908`?

Comment: See also [how to determine the available physical memory in linux](http://stackoverflow.com/a/19387953/14558)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One way is to filter the output with something like:

```
grep MemTotal /proc/meminfo | sed 's/[^0-9]//g'
```

This will remove all characters that aren't digits, as per the following transcript:

```
pax:~$ grep MemTotal /proc/meminfo
MemTotal:        4122788 kB

pax:~$ grep MemTotal /proc/meminfo | sed 's/[^0-9]//g'
4122788
```

Answer (score 1):

Try adding this: `|awk '{print $2}'`

Answer (score 1):

besides looking at /proc/meminfo, any of the following commands on LINUX will help: **free**, **top**